# How to access a site running with a different applicatio pool account

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a piece of code executing inside a SPWeb, which has to create a SPSIte and SPWeb objects of sites in a different Web Application runing with a different application pool account. I am getting an error like this:

Error: An exception has occurred.   ExceptionType: 'SqlException'   ExceptionMessage: 'Cannot open database "WSS_Content_Team_Standard_01" requested by the login. The login failed.    Login failed for user 'IINET\UATSP_MyAppool Acc'.'    '

How do i achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the app pool account for the context web app does not have permissions to the content db of the "remote" SPSite. This is actually a good thing from a security perspective.

One way to work around this problem is to call a (custom) webservice or HTTP Handler hosted by the remote SPSite which does the actual work that requires access to the content db.

I personally would not try to go down the route of windows impersonation or changing db permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating new SPSite Object from the given Site Collection and passing Web App pool user token as parameter for it.The new SPSite object should be under seperate SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrevileges